"OpenSSL 3.0's legacy provider failed to load"
When I started Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3),the following error message floats and I could not figure out hhow to resolve it.
"Error while loading conda entry point: conda-content-trust (OpenSSL 3.0's legacy provider failed to load. This is a fatal error by default, but cryptography supports running without legacy algorithms by setting the environment variable CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY. If you did not expect this error, you have likely made a mistake with your OpenSSL configuration.)"
I have tried many proposed solutions from (https://stackoverflow.com) and others and none of them resolve the issue.

conda install cryptography


If you are using linux / Mac then add this command to .bashrc or .zshrc file

export CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY=1
and then run
source ./bashrc or ./zshrc 


If you are using Window
Under "System variables",
click "New..." and add CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY as the variable name and 1 as the value.
Click "OK" to save the changes.


Thank you very much, Sanjyay!

I run the "condo install cryptography"
When run "conda update conda" still it was floating the same error like what i have posted in the question ----> then I exit the anaconda prompt.  continue with editting the system varibale and value as recommended.
Restart the terminal and run "conda update conda" ---> no more error was displayed.

So it works to solve the issue.
Many thanks.

if you are using apt, install lib with apt install -y python3-cryptography

In Arch Linux I had this error when trying to create a new conda environment. So, I could not install the cryptography package directly with conda.
My solution was to first to install the python-cryptography package with pacman (or with the installer of your Linux distribution)
pacman -S python-cryptography

And then adding export CRYPTOGRAPHY_OPENSSL_NO_LEGACY=1 to .bashrc (or .zshrc) file
And finally execute:
source ./bashrc  (or source ./zshrc)
